# working with ListView server control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am working on ListView, displaying data from database, when i run my application i am getting this problem "Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'  ",
not getting the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the account your application pool is running under in IIS does not have any permissions on the SQL Sever.

[See here for how to change that account](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/), you need to either set a different account, give the account that it's running under permissions in SQL server, or both.

Comment: +1 straight answer to a very common problem with app pools :-)